# CRUD - LARAVEL 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, crud, collection

Estou desenvolvendo um CRUD e no meu controller eu tenho a função create:

```
public function create()
{
    $neighborhood = new Neighborhood();
    $city = new City();
    return view( view: 'admin.cities.create', compact( varname: 'city', _:'neighborhood'));
}
```

O objetivo é Criar a cidade(City) e o Bairro(Neighborhood) ao mesmo tempo caso não tenha bairro relacionado a Cidade. Segue abaixo a View:

```
@section('content')
    <h3>Nova Cidade</h3>
    <form method="post" action="{{ route('cities.store') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Nome da Cidade</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="city_name" value="{{ old('name', $city-name) }}">
        </div>

        @if ($neighborhood->id == '')
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nome do Bairro</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="name" name="neighborhood_name" value="{{ old('name', $neighborhood->name) }}">
            </div>
        @endif

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Criar</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

A minha dúvida está em como vou gravar as informações na function store. Segue abaixo a function:

```
public function store(Request $request, City $city, Neighborhood $neighborhood)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $city->name->$data['city_name'];
    $neighborhood->name->$data['neighborhood'];
    Client::create();
    Neighborhood::create();
    $city->neighborhoods()->create($neighborhood);
}
```

E abaixo segue o erro:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
>   Array to string conversion

O erro eu consegui interpretar, pelo que parece na linha 
 54 a variável $data['city_name'] é um array e precisa ser uma string. Mas como fazer isto?

Gostaria de uma ajuda também com a linhas 56 que deve ser para criar no banco e a linha 57 que cria o neighborhood atrelado a cidade.

Já tenho uma relação one-to-many no meu Model City para que eu possa utilizar o comando na linha 57. Segue abaixo.

```
class City extendes Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function neighborhoods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany( related: Neighborhood::class);
    }
}
```

Espero ter conseguido me fazer entender. Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda.

Comment: Me desculpe. Irei ler o material acima citado.